# SQL - Filter based on one or more parameters but not all of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I am trying to script a query which has 3 parameters but be able to only populate any combination of the three, either one of them, any two of them or all three.

The query I have tried is as follows, could you please advise what I am doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(255) =''
DECLARE @Parameter2 NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @Parameter3 NVARCHAR(10) = ''

SELECT x.*  
from
(
SELECT 

list of columns for various tables

,case when len(@Parameter1) > 1 and apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' +@Parameter1 + '%' ) then 1 else 0 end [Parameter1]
,case when len(@Parameter2) > 1 and p.plan_name like ('%' + @Parameter2 + '%' ) then 1 else 0 end [Parameter2]
,case when len(@Parameter3) > 1 and r.res_code like ('%' + @Parameter3 + '%' ) then 1 else 0 end [Parameter3]

  FROM [LFB_Vision_GazAdmin].[dbo].[Gtablename] gap

  left outer join [dbo].[table2] as ap on ap.PLAN_ID=gap.PLAN_ID
  left outer join dbo.table3 p on p.plan_ID = p.PLAN_ID
  left outer join dbo.table4  as apa on ap.[ACTION_ID] = apa.ACTION_ID
  left outer join dbo.table5 R ON GAP.FCL_URN = R.FCL_URN
--  where 
--   (apa.ACTION_DESCRIPTION like ('%' + @Parameter1 + '%')
--OR p.PLAN_NAME like ('%' + @Parameter2 + '%')
--OR R.RESPONSECODE = @Parameter3 
--   )
) x 
where (
      (x.Parameter1=1 and (x.Parameter2=0 and x.Parameter3=0))
   or (x.Parameter2=1 and (x.Parameter1=0 and x.Parameter3=0))
   or (x.Parameter3=1 and (x.Parameter1=0 and x.Parameter2=0))
   or (x.Parameter3=0 and (x.Parameter1=1 and x.Parameter2=1))
   or (x.Parameter2=0 and (x.Parameter1=1 and x.Parameter3=1))
   or (x.Parameter1=0 and (x.Parameter2=1 and x.Parameter3=1))
   or (x.Parameter1=1 and x.Parameter2=1 and x.Parameter3=1)
      )
```

The above query works if I only populate one of the parameters but if I populate two or all three then it gives me more rows as it gives me data which pertains two the first OR the second parameter. I would like it to take both parameters into account if two are populated and all three into account if all three are populated.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: *could you please advise what I am doing wrong?* ... first, tell us what is wrong -error? undesired results?

Comment: @Parfait , it works if I only populate one of the parameters but if I populate two or all three then it gives me more rows as it gives me data which pertains two the first OR the second parameter. I would like it to take both parameters into account if two are populated and all three into account if all three are populated.

Comment: Did you attempt that logic at all? Is that what the `WHERE` clauses are for or are those clauses unrelated to @Parameter# especially since both sets are different types?

Answer (score 0):

I can't perform an actual test without the actual data -

But I think you can do something like the following to achieve the expected result

You don't actually need the `CTE` and the `CASE` statements

```
DECLARE
    @param1 Nvarchar(10) = 'a', -- if Empty will not be considered as Filter
    @param2 Nvarchar(10) = 'f', -- if Empty will not be considered as Filter
    @param3 Nvarchar(10) = '' -- if Empty will not be considered as Filter

-- IF all @params are Empty, it will return all Rows


Select
    sReference,
    sDescription,
    sIMEI

From TelematicDevices td

Where 
    -- Will be TRUE if the @param1 = '' (means not filtered based on param1) 
    -- and will not search based on param1
    (td.sReference LIKE ('%' + @param1 + '%') OR @param1 = '')
    AND
    (td.sDescription LIKE ('%' + @param2 + '%') OR @param2 = '')
    AND
    (td.sIMEI LIKE ('%' + @param3 + '%') OR @param3 = '')
```

with the following params

```
DECLARE
    @param1 Nvarchar(10) = '', 
    @param2 Nvarchar(10) = 'hon', 
    @param3 Nvarchar(10) = ''
```

i get the following result

[image]

and if I change Params to

```
DECLARE
    @param1 Nvarchar(10) = '', 
    @param2 Nvarchar(10) = 'hon', 
    @param3 Nvarchar(10) = '83'
```

i get

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. That worked perfectly. The where clause is exactly what I needed. I was overcomplicating this.